# How can I configure my side mouse button to show all open applications like it does on Windows?

Tags: mouse, shortcuts, application-switcher

If you use Windows 10 and have a mouse button where your right thumb grips the mouse you know there is a button right there that brings up all open applications so you don't have to search for the application you need by minimizing and maximizing multiple terminals, Chrome windows, or open folders, etc.
How can I do this on Ubuntu? I have 22.04 installed.

There are a few buttons for the right thumb on my mouse (pictured). The button I want to assign is not the visible buttons, but the button where the thumb rests which I have circled and drawn an arrow to.
I want this button to show all applications.

[image]

[image]

I can get the event I want to happen which shows all applications in the middle of the screen on Ubuntu on my keyboard with the 'super button', which is a Windows icon on my keyboard.

I typed `xev` into the terminal and I get the following when I press the button I get the following output...

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 4499173, (71,111), root:(1150,598),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 4499179, (71,111), root:(1150,598),
    state 0x14, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   32  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 4499203, (71,111), root:(1150,598),
    state 0x1c, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x6800001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 4499211, (71,111), root:(1150,598),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Then, when I press the 'super button' which is the Windows icon on my keyboard in `xev` I get the following...

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyPointer

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
        32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 7757428, (83,7), root:(213,121),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus NO, state 16

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 7758496, (83,7), root:(213,121),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus NO, state 16

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyPointer

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
        32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 7774794, (83,7), root:(213,121),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus NO, state 16

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0xb00, subw 0x0, time 7775929, (83,7), root:(213,121),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus NO, state 16
```

Comment: 2 things: there is a command called `xev`. Start it from commandline and it will show the keycodes for all keys pressed. Check if the button press is shown. If it does not that needs to be addressed 1st. 2. if it does ... is there software that does what you want? If there is you can assign the command line version to the mouse button but if not ... it needs to be coded and that is off topic here.

Comment: On my keyboard I press fn+F5 to see all the applications. It's what I want, but I don't know what it's called. But it is something the system knows how to do / does already.

Comment: I updated my OP with your help @Rinzwind

Comment: Not sure how to get it with your comments but I appreciate it. I updated the OP again with the output of `xev` when I press fn+F5, which is the desired action I want to happen. A lot of info and I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Hold up, the function I want doesn't happen with fn+F5, it's the super button I press which gives me all the applications on the whole screen. Not sure I'm getting a 'keycode' for this button.